# Install perl library from GitHub

Tags: perl

I have a perl library that I want to make accessible to others (to accompany an R package I'm developing). I currently have my library - `vcfParser` - in a directory called `bin` in my working directory. In another script `callParser.pl` I tell perl where to find the library, and then I call one of the functions later in the script.

**vcfParser.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package vcfParser;

{...}

1;
```

**callParser.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use File::Spec;
use lib File::Spec->catdir($FindBin::Bin, 'bin/');

use vcfParser;
```

This approach works, but relies on my library being in the `bin` directory.

I would like to have this easily available for others to use as a standalone module. Is there a way to make a perl library available from a Github repository?

If not, what's the most suitable way for me to allow others to easily install my library?

In R packages from Github are commonly installed using:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("fugu/myProject")
library(myProject)
```

Comment: Make a package in exactly the same way that you would if you wanted to publish on CPAN. Then put it on Github. (But seriously consider publishing to CPAN too)

Comment: `git clone ... && cd  ... && cpanm --installdeps . && cpanm .`